# How do I get ride of an Annoying Alert?

Tags: alert

I get the following annoying alert randomly, usually when I launch an application.  I believe I got this bug when I consented to have my disk scanned by some proprietary security application.

The message varies from an offer to enhance disk storage to protecting sensitive information.

Where is its source and how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you've been infected by adware. There are some pretty good tutorials out there on how to deal with this